# SimpleCov code coverage comparize with last build in Jenkins

Tags: ruby, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, simplecov

I have situation where I want to compare code coverage of last Jenkins build from current Jenkins build so if current Jenkins build code coverage is low then last one , build should unstable or failed

Is that possible with any Jenkins plugin or do I need to do some stuff with SimpleCov?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the RUbyMetrics Jenkins plugin: https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/RubyMetrics+plugin

along with with `simplecov-json` and `simplecov-rcov` gems.

So you need to add this to your `rspec_helper`:

```
require 'simplecov'
require 'simplecov-json'
require 'simplecov-rcov'

SimpleCov.formatters = [
  SimpleCov::Formatter::HTMLFormatter,
  SimpleCov::Formatter::JSONFormatter,
  SimpleCov::Formatter::RcovFormatter
]
SimpleCov.start
```